# rails+postgres migration empty string vs nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, migration

I ran a this migration:

```
def up
  add_column :product_customers, :name, :string
  add_column :product_customers, :email, :string
end

def down
  remove_column :product_customers, :name, :string
  remove_column :product_customers, :email, :string
end
```

Then I tried to run this one but didn't work:

```
def up
  change_column_null :product_customers, :name, false
  change_column_null :product_customers, :email, false
end

def down
  change_column_null :product_customers, :name, true
  change_column_null :product_customers, :email, true
end
```

I was surprised and didn't understand how it was possible. Then I hit up the console and realized that the value of the fields were not `""` but `nil`. I checked then a few other tables and saw that some tables and fields have `""` as default and some have `nil`.

I'd like to have the empty strings in all the tables. So my questions:

1. When I generate a new migration how can I make sure my string type columns will have `""` as default. So for instance what should I have done differently in the code I provided?
2. What's the convention to change the `nil` values to `""` for existing tables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1. **When I generate a new migration how can I make sure my string type columns will have "" as default. So for instance what should I have done differently in the code I provided?**

[Documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Migration.html) has you [covered](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements/add_column):

```
add_column :product_customers, :name, :string, default: ""
```

If you want to disallow `NULL` value in your DB columns, then also add `null: false` to your migration:

```
add_column :product_customers, :name, :string, default: "", null: false
```

---

> 2. **What's the convention to change the nil values to "" for existing tables?**

To change column's default value use `change_column_default`. if you want to change the DB rule for allowing `NULL` values, use `change_column_null`.

Comment: Uzbekjon, could you tell me why some of them were `nil` and some of them were `""`? I haven't set the default anywhere.

Comment: You must have set it while creating in your controller where your `param[:field]` had a value of `""`. The ones with `nil` value could have been created differently, without that `field` being set in your `params` or in rails console.

Comment: One last question. Are you using `""` as default or `nil` for string columns as default in your projects? Should someone sticking with one or there are some cases when one is better than the other?

Comment: Well, that would depend on your business requirements or your project code. Do you want to check for `nil` every time you want access it? Do you call any other `String` methods on that field for manipulation?

Comment: Okay. So let's take this example above. `product_customer.name` should be never empty when user fills the form. I can make it with validation. Is that enough or you think I should add the null constraint in the db as well? I can see it's more consistent if it's `nil` in the db but way more convenient fi I use `""`. So there is now explicit answer to this question?

Comment: A university module on DB design makes me always have consistent and valid data in my tables. So, I would definitely add the `not null` rule to my schema (db layer) and add validation in my model (application layer). If it would be more convenient if that column had a `""` value by default, I would overwrite a getter method in my model. Having a `NULL`  value in DB allows for more efficient storage and query optimizations. So, if the `name` field should never be `nil`, then you have your model validation to ensure that. But if someone tries to create it in DB, you have your DB validation set.